# Converting a string into an array with Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

I am trying to convert the below strings into arrays so I can loop through them.  I would like to avoid using ?eval.

```
item = "x, y, z, a"
itemPrice = "1, 2, 3, 4"
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The expected output is to turn this into an array I can reference in code (ie ${item[0]}) or adding up price totals based on the item and itemPrice. Also to add, I would like a different solution that ?eval would give me.

Answer (score 3):

You can just [split](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_string.html#ref_builtin_split) this string:

```
<#assign items="x, y, z, a"?split(", ") >

<#list items as item>
${item}
</#list>
```